# Can two girls who love each other be together without marriage nor physical relations?

Tags: halal-haram, homosexuality, love

I'm an unmarried Muslim girl and I love another girl. We don't have any physical relation but we love each other like a boyfriend and girlfriend. We have decided we will never marry any boy and we will be together forever. But no physical relation. Is it halal in Islam?

Comment: Even if you don't intend to act on your impulses, this seems like something that might very likely lead to a haram action, thereby making it haram as well. Swearing that you will not marry anyone [is in itself haram](https://islamqa.info/en/87998)